# Adding an extra url to a HNSC

Tags: site-collection, url, alternate-access-mapping, host-named, hnsc

In our intranet we have one web application with an empty root site collection and one Host Named Site collection with this url `http://test` which is in use and it is functioning without problem. Now we want to access this site collection with another url allso. How we can manage it? do we need to configure Alternate access mapping? How you can access same site collection with two different urls?

**UPDATE**: I used Set-SPSiteUrl to add another url to the site collection on Custom Zone. Now users can acccess the site by using the second url but singel Sign On not working. Did I do right?

Comment: You should create a new question regarding the single sign-on issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use AAM to specify multiple URL for one web application (not site collection).
It might be needed to do also modifications to IIS settings.

Here are some useful resources:

- [Plan alternate access mappings for SP 2007/2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Plan alternate access mappings for SP 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I add an extra url to the site collection using set-spsiteurl powershell command like this: set-spsiteurl -Identity http://test1 -Url http://test2 Zone Custom . Now users access the site collecion by entering http://test2 -Zone Custom but single sign on not working.